# How kill process ID remotely Bash

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, grep, kill-process

On linux device, the following process ID runs:

[image]

I'm trying to kill the process ids related to ads2 (shown in the image above) remotely (through a bash script that runs on another device). So I tried:

```
ssh nvidia@"id-address" "kill pgrep ads2"
```

where `pgrep` returns the process IDs related to `ads2`. When i run the script it prompts me to enter the password and then nothing happen, i mean the processes are not terminated.

However, i can't figure out where the error is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ``ssh nvidia@"id-address" "pkill ads2"`` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kill` expects a number (or list of numbers) following it. `pgrep ads2` is just words!

For bash to replace the words `pgrep ads2` with the result of running that command to produce `kill 15951 15995` you can use backticks.

i.e. : `` kill `pgrep ads2` ``  will first run `pgrep ads` and then `kill (result of pgrep ads2)`

However, as you are performing this over ssh, your computer would run the backticks before the remote. I.e. `pgrep ads` would be run on your local machine, and `kill` on the remote, which wouldn't work. So you must escape the backticks like so:

```
ssh nvidia@"id-address" "kill \`pgrep ads2\`"
```

Comment: Thanlks for the answer. This works for me perfectly. However, it promts me to enter the password for the remote device and i'm wondering if i could pass the password in the script ^ ^  instead of typing it manually?

Comment: @Zang322 : As this is a completely different problem, I suggest that you ask a different question - of course after having unsuccessfully googled for _provide password for ssh from script_ or something like this.

Comment: @user1934428 you're write. Thnaks